# Can I somehow call the derived class method while looping through vector<shared_ptr<BaseClass>>?

Tags: c++

I have the following problem:

```
class Component
{
public:
virtual void update(){};
};


class TestComponent : public Component
{
    void update()override;
};


class GameObject
{
public :
void addComponent(Component& comp)
{
 std::shared_ptr<Component> test = std::make_shared<Component>(comp);
 components.push_back(test);
}
void GameObject::update()
{
 for(auto comp : components)
 {
 //I want to call the derived update here without casting it to the derived class if possible
 comp->update();
 }
}
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Component>> components;
};

Somewhere else in my code:

GameObject go;
TestComponent comp;
go.addComponent(comp);
```

I would just assume that when I add an object to the vector of Components that I can simply call update on all of the vectors elements and it uses the overridden update of the object I passed into addComponent. So for my example above I expect the forloop to call the update of the TestComponent I added and not the baseclass update. But thats not whats happening so I assume I am missing something.
Or maybe my approach is just wrong in general. I am not really sure about my usage of a sharedpointer for this?
Any hints in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no `TestComponent` objects in your vector.  They are all `Component`s.

```
void addComponent(Component& comp)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Component> test = std::make_shared<Component>(comp);
    components.push_back(test);
}
```

In this function, you create a new `Component` object that s a *copy* of the `Component` sub-object of the `TestComponent` object you passed in.  This is known as [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

You will need to either avoid copying the objects or implement some sort of cloneable interface.

To avoid copying the object, you can do something like this:

```
class GameObject
{
public:
    void addComponent(std::shared_ptr<Component> comp)
    {
        components.push_back(comp);
    }
    // ...
};

int main() {
    GameObject go;
    std::shared_ptr<TestComponent> testComponent = std::make_shared<TestComponent>();
    go.addComponent(testComponent);
}
```

In this case, `main` and `go` share ownership of a single `TestComponent` object.  If you want to avoid that, you could implement a clonable interface so that objects know how to copy themselves:

```
class Component
{
public:
    virtual void update(){};
    virtual std::shared_ptr<Component> clone() const
    {
        return std::make_shared<Component>(*this);
    }
};


class TestComponent : public Component
{
    void update() override;
    std::shared_ptr<Component> clone() const override
    {
        return std::make_shared<TestComponent>(*this);
    }
};

class GameObject
{
public:
    void addComponent(const Component& comp)
    {
        components.push_back(comp.clone());
    }
    // ...
};

int main()
{
    GameObject go;
    TestComponent comp;
    go.addComponent(comp);
}
```

In this case, you still make a copy, but every class has to override the `clone` method.

---

As for the question about `shared_ptr`: `std::shared_ptr` is a smart pointer that shares ownership of an object between multiple owners.  An object owned by one or more `std::shared_ptr`s is only destroyed when all of the `std::shared_ptr` objects sharing ownership of it are destroyed.  If you don't need this behavior, then `std::unique_ptr` exists and will be somewhat more performant.  `std::unique_ptr` models unique ownership.  Only one `std::unique_ptr` object can ever reference an object at a time, and the object is destroyed when that `std::unique_ptr` is destroyed.

Either type of smart pointer could be used in this situation:

- Use `std::shared_ptr` if you want a `GameObject` to be able to share ownership of its components with other owners (perhaps other `GameObjects`).
- Use `std::unique_ptr` if you want a `GameObject` to have exclusive ownership of its components.  In this case the `GameObject` could still allow other objects to access its components, but the components' lifetimes would be tied to the lifetime of the `GameObject`

Comment: Beat me too the punch, however I think you did not emphasize how the second solution ( aka the copy ) defeats the purpose of using a shared_ptr to completely answer the question.

Comment: @ChrisMc That depends on what operations exist on the `GameObject` class.  In this limited example you're right, `unique_ptr` would be a better option, but it may be that OP wants other objects to be able to retrieve and share ownership of the components owned by the `GameObject`, but for some reason still wants to always copy the component when it's added.

Comment: @Galik the `auto comp` is a copy of the shared_ptr not the `TestComponent`, so there is no slicing there.

Comment: no disagreement there. It is the second to last line of the question "I am not really sure about my usage of a sharedpointer for this?" is all I'm _suggesting_ you address. =)

Comment: @ChrisMc I didn't even see that sentence.  Added a bit about that.

Comment: Thank you! I knew about object slicing but I thought that passing by reference would avoid that. Also I tried the craziest things but never thought about the simple thing of just passing over a shared_ptr of the component... But one more question. I also thought that I could solve it by using templates. What would be the better approach here, templates or passing in a sharedpointer?

Answer (score 1):

To make your code compile just add another method, rest are fine . Since update method is virtual and the base class is non-abstract, both can call update without any issue.

```
void TestComponent::addComponent(const TestComponent & tcomp)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Component> test = std::make_shared<TestComponent >(tcomp);
    components.push_back(test);
}
```

Edited: For adding any component, derived or base class, use this way:

```
void TestComponent::addComponent(std::shared_ptr<Component> comp)
{
    components.push_back(comp);
}
```

Comment: That may work for Testcomponent but I expect to have dozens of different Components and it would be kinda overkill to add a method for every single component. But actually I could in fact make use of templates, right?

Comment: @Wuceng: Edited just now for adding different components.